# What challenges could I face managing different competitors on a client assignment?

Tags: project-management

My next role is of a Program Manager managing inter-dependencies between multiple projects and involves daily program management until the program cycle ends. Each project is being delivered by a different competitor (to my company). I would be the only one working from my company on this program, the rest of the personnel are from the client or other competitors.

What challenges could arise in this kind of setting?

Comment: @Kilisi  They are competitors to my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What challenges could arise in this kind of setting?

If they're all professionals there should be few issues except normal ones. In theory everyone would be out to impress (including yourself).

What you need to watch for is personality clashes and deadlines, which is absolutely normal whether they're competitors or not. As a matter of course you would be keeping detailed documentation on everything and covering your own back. So be watchful but not unduly worried. I've been in this situation many times, no one wants to be the show stopper since it's all in the industry and a good chance to impress and network.

I've worked on projects with and get on very well with most of the techs in my area despite competing directly with their companies. To the extent that professional courtesy would get my issues prioritised and vice versa. So this is actually a great opportunity for you in some respects.

You may get the odd person playing up, but that's rare and easy to solve and you can get that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing your thoughts and experience. Can you please advise if there could be any other methods apart from detailed documentation?

Comment: Detailed documentation is just normal... everything is normal, get to know the people in a professional capacity, judge their competence and assign them what suits their skillset and things should be smooth.